# Retorno da chamada cURL no PHP não está em JSON

Tags: php, html, json, api, libcurl

Alguém sabe me dizer porque os dados não retornam de forma estruturada? Preciso tirar os dados da api https://swapi.dev/api/people/ e gostaria que retornasse em formato json, porém já tentei de inúmeras formas e não consegui.

```
<?php

$headers = array("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
$url = "https://swapi.dev/api/people/";
$ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$resultado = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));

var_dump($resultado);
?>
```

O ideal seria o retorno como na estrutura abaixo:

```
{
    "birth_year": "19 BBY",
    "eye_color": "Blue",
    "films": [
        "https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/",
        ...
    ],
    "gender": "Male",
    "hair_color": "Blond",
    "height": "172",
    "homeworld": "https://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/",
    "mass": "77",
    "name": "Luke Skywalker",
    "skin_color": "Fair",
    "created": "2014-12-09T13:50:51.644000Z",
    "edited": "2014-12-10T13:52:43.172000Z",

}
```

Porém está me retornando assim:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (4) { ["count"]=> int(82) ["next"]=> string(35) "http://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=2" ["previous"]=> NULL ["results"]=> array(10) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (16) { ["name"]=> string(14) "Luke Skywalker" ["height"]=> string(3) "172" ["mass"]=> string(2) "77" ["hair_color"]=> string(5) "blond" ["skin_color"]=> string(4) "fair" ["eye_color"]=> string(4) "blue" ["birth_year"]=> string(5) "19BBY" ["gender"]=> string(4) "male" ["homeworld"]=> string(31) "http://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/" ["films"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(29) "http://swapi.dev/api/films/1/" [1]=> string(29) "http://swapi.dev/api/films/2/" [2]=> string(29) "http://swapi.dev/api/films/3/" [3]=> string(29) "http://swapi.dev/api/films/6/" } ["species"]=> array(0) { } ["vehicles"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(33) "http://swapi.dev/api/vehicles/14/" [1]=> string(33) "http://swapi.dev/api/vehicles/30/" } ["starships"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(34) "http://swapi.dev/api/starships/12/" [1]=> string(34) "http://swapi.dev/api/starships/22/" } ["created"]=> string(27) "2014-12-09T13:50:51.644000Z" ["edited"]=> string(27) "2014-12-20T21:17:56.891000Z" ["url"]=> string(30) "http://swapi.dev/api/people/1/" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#4 (16) { ["name"]=> string(5) "C-3PO" ["height"]=> string(3) "167" ["mass"]=> string(2) "75" ["hair_color"]=> string(3) "n/a" ["skin_color"]=> string(4) "gold" ["eye_color"]=> string(6) "yellow" ["birth_year"]=> string(6) "112BBY" ["gender"]=> string(3) "n/a" ["homeworld"]=> string(31) "http://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/" ["films"]=> array(6) { [0]=> string(29) "http://swapi.dev/api/films/1/" [1]=> string(29) "http://swapi.dev/api/films/2/" [2]=> string(29) "http://swapi.dev/api/films/3/" [3]=> string(29) "http://swapi.dev/api/films/4/" [4]=> string(29) "http://swapi.dev/api/films/5/" [5]=> string(29) "http://swapi.dev/api/films/6/" } ["species"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(31) "http://swapi.dev/api/species/2/" } ["vehicles"]=> array(0) { } ["starships"]=> array(0) { } ["created"]=> string(27) "2014-12-10T15:10:51.357000Z" ["edited"]=> string(27) "2014-12-20T21:17:50.309000Z" ["url"]=> string(30) "http://swapi.dev/api/people/2/" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#5 (16) { ["name"]=> string(5) "R2-D2" ["height"]=> string(2) "96" ["mass"]=> string(2) "32" ["hair_color"]=> string(3) "n/a" ["skin_color"]=> string(11) "white, blue" ["eye_color"]=> string(3) "red" ["birth_year"]=> string(5) "33BBY" ["gender"]=> string(3) "n/a" ["homeworld"]=> string(31) "http://swapi.dev/api/planets/8/" ["films"]=> array(6) { [0]=> string(29) "http://swapi.dev/api/films/1/" [1]=> string(29) "http://swapi.dev/api/films/2/" [2]=> string(29) "http://swapi.dev/api/films/3/" [3]=> string(29) "http://swapi.dev/api/films/4/" [4]=> string(29) "http://swapi.dev/api/films/5/" [5]=> string(29) "http://swapi.dev/api/films/6/" } ["species"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(31) "http://swapi.dev/api/species/2/" } ["vehicles"]=> array(0) { } ["starships"]=> array(0) { } ["created"]=> string(27) "2014-12-10T15:11:50.376000Z" ["edited"]=> string(27) "2014-12-20T21:17:50.311000Z" ["url"]=> string(30) "http://swapi.dev/api/people/3/" } [3]=> object(stdClass)#6 (16) { ["name"]=> string(11) "Darth Vader" ["height"]=> string(3) "202" ["mass"]=> string(3) "136" ["hair_color"]=> string(4) "none" ["skin_color"]=> string(5) "white" ["eye_color"]=> string(6) "yellow" ["birth_year"]=> string(7) "41.9BBY" ["gender"]=> string(4) "male" ["homeworld"]=> string(31) "http://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/" ["films"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(29) "http://swapi.dev/api/films/1/" [1]=> string(29) "http://swapi.dev/api/films/2/" [2]=> string(29)
```

Comment: Ao remover o json_decode você tem ter a string da maneira que foi retornada. Ou seja, igual ao resultado que você disse ser o desejado. Qual o motivo de usar o json_decode? Já que o trabalho dessa função é retornar um objeto ou array exatamente como está te retornando.

Comment: Estou fazendo esse código com base em uma aula. Nessa aula não é colocado os headers, apenas o json_decode, os headers inclui depois para teste e ver se rodava. Tirei o json_decode e continua retornando como texto :c

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia.
O problema está no json_decode, ele tem um parâmetro a mais que define se o retorno vai ser um array associativo ou um objeto, como você não está passando esse parâmetro ele usa o parâmetro default que é false e retorna um objeto. passe o segundo parâmetro como true para retornar um array.

```
$resultado = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
```

Fonte: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Amigo, coloquei como passou e continua da mesma forma. Exclui os headers tanto do curl quando da variável em cima e também continua igual.

Comment: Ola.  
Então, se for para trabalhar com os dados em PHP não tem muita escolha, ou você decoda os dados para um objeto ou para um array.  
Agora se for só para printar o resultado na tela igual o exemplo, você  pode tentar usar o print_r no lugar do var_dump e reencodar os o resultado de volta para json passando o parâmetro JSON_PRETTY_PRINT no json_encode.  
EX:  
`print_r(  json_encode( $resultado, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT ) );`

Comment: É que eu não entendo, porque o desse cara [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tIterRjj8mk&list=LL&index=1&t=641s) deu certo e o meu não?

Comment: Não me parece que o formato dos resultados estarem diferentes seja um erro de código, talvez seja algum plugin  do navegador que esteja formatando o resultado dele. 
Eu encontrei esse [plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formattersupport-php/gejgppbbjeaebpkolahnbfehkfnlbdnc/related) para o chrome que deixou o resultado na minha maquina igual o do video.

Comment: Ok amigo, com o plugin rodou. Obrigado!!